# Is it possible to programatically set the "from:" field in a Firefox file open dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, opendialog

I am generating a file open dialog which allows the user to download a blob I have generated in code. This works fine but in Firefox the "from:" field on the open dialog looks like:

> from: blob:

Is it possible to programmatically set this with javascript so that I can specify the domain the data actually originates from?

For example if the blob was generated from data on www.stackoverflow.com I would like the open dialog to look like:

> from: www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot influence the "From:" description in the Save dialog. Otherwise folks would abuse this.

However, it is indeed unfortunate that blob URIs display this poorly. Consider [filing a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) (or even creating a patch) to rectify this.

Comment: Revisiting this as I find it is still an issue. I submitted a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1046240) as per your suggestion. It appears to have been acknowledged but has yet to be fixed.